# Приходит уведомление на почту в виде HTML

Tags: html, wordpress, форма, email

Пользователь оставил комментарий по товару через форму на сайте вордпресс, но на почту приходит уведомление не с текстом, а с html-кодом с этим отзывом. Почему не корректно отображается?

Answer (score 0):

В админке нужно было выствить птичку в поле Send Emails in Plain Text